# ImportError: No module named visual.graph

Tags: python, graph, vpython

Why i am getting this error?

```
ImportError: No module named visual.graph
```

I think `vpython` is istalled.

I get this message in CMD ANACONDA when I try to install it :

```
(base) C:\Users\vitor>conda install -c mwcraig vpython
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - astropy
  - vpython
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I don't know why it is not working. My code :

```
from visual.graph import *
graph = gdisplay (x = 0,y = 0, width = 500, height = 300)
function = gcurve(color = color.red)
for x in arange (0., 5.0 , 0.01):
    rate(40)
    y = sin(30 * x) + sin(33 * x)
    function.plot( pos=(x , y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "Classic VPython" or the new VPython 7. The visual module only works in "Classic VPython" and not in the new VPython 7. Here is a graph demo program in Classic Vpython

https://github.com/vpython/visual/blob/master/examples/graphtest.py

and here is a graph demo program in VPYthon 7.

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/GraphTest

http://www.glowscript.org/#/user/GlowScriptDemos/folder/Examples/program/GraphTest/edit

To run it under VPython 7 replace first line in code above

GlowScript 2.7 VPython

with

from vpython import *

See vpython.org for details about vpython 7 and how it differs from classic vpython.